# Reusing multiple switch cases and if-else statements

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I am creating a 2D text-based Drawing Application which can draw basic shapes like Line, Rectangle, Triangle, Circle, Oval. The Line can be drawn in eight directions on a 2D plane and can be moved by a user in Left, Right, Up and Down directions.

The Lines(or any other Shape) are contained within a Boundary. Lines(or any other Shape) must respect the boundary and warn the user when he tries to move the Line beyond the Boundary, here's the visual example,

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
*         6         7         8           * 
*           6       7       8             * 
*             6     7     8               * 
*               6   7   8                 * 
*                 6 7 8                   * 
*         5 5 5 5 5 8 1 1 1 1 1           * 
*                 4 3 2                   * 
*               4   3   2                 * 
*             4     3     2               * 
*           4       3       2             * 
*         4         3         2           * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
*                                         * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

In the above diagram, the Boundary is made of `*` marks and the numbers 1-8 represent each possible line on a 2D plane.

Since there are 8 types of Line and each line can be moved-in 4 possible directions, this is how  I am detecting whether the user move was valid or not( Move is valid if the Line moved is within the Boundary).

So let' say the Line was (0,x) which means it grows linearly only on x-coordinate (East Direction Only) and user moved it in Left direction,

```
//I am repeating below logic for each different type of Line

if( lineYCoordinate == 0 && lineXCoordinate == 1 ){ //Detect what type of line it was

   switch( User.Move){ // Detect what move did user made

     case LEFT: {
                    //check if line is overlapping the window
          // if overlapping warn user else move the line
          }

    case RIGHT: {
                    //check if line is overlapping the window
          // if overlapping warn user else move the line
          }

    case UP: {
                    //check if line is overlapping the window
          // if overlapping warn user else move the line
          } 

    case DOWN: {
                    //check if line is overlapping the window
          // if overlapping warn user else move the line
          }

       }
}
```

So here's the problem, the above entire logic was just for one type of Line. Currently, I am repeating the same logic for other 7 types of Lines too. The logic to determine whether the Line is overlapping with Boundary depends on which type of Line it was and in which direction it was moved.

How can I refactor this logic, so that I can reuse or minimize the multiple switch and if-else constructs?

As advised, this is the method which I want to refactor.

```
boolean isOverlappingWindow(Window window, Utils.MenuOption option) {
        boolean isOverlapping = false;

//rInc & cInc is equivalent as x, y coordinate respectively

        if (rInc == 0 && cInc == 1) { //detect line type

            switch (option) { //detect user move
                case DOWN: {
                    if ((rb + 2) > window.lastRowForBorder) {
                        --rb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case RIGHT: {
                    if ((cb + length + 2) > window.lastColumnForBorder) {
                        --cb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case LEFT: {
                    if (cb < window.firstColumnForBorder) {
                        ++cb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case UP: {
                    if (rb < window.firstRowForBorder) {
                        ++rb;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (rInc == 1 && cInc == 0) {

            switch (option) {
                case DOWN: {
                    if ((rb + length + 2) > window.lastRowForBorder) {
                        --rb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case RIGHT: {
                    if ((cb + 2) > window.lastColumnForBorder) {
                        --cb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case LEFT: {
                    if (cb < window.firstColumnForBorder) {
                        ++cb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case UP: {
                    if (rb < window.firstRowForBorder) {
                        ++rb;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (rInc == 0 && cInc == -1) {

            switch (option) {
                case DOWN: {
                    if ((rb + 2) > window.lastRowForBorder) {
                        --rb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case RIGHT: {
                    if ((cb + 2) > window.lastColumnForBorder) {
                        --cb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case LEFT: {
                    if ((Math.abs(length - cb)) < window.firstColumnForBorder) {
                        ++cb;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case UP: {
                    if (rb < window.firstRowForBorder) {
                        ++rb;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (rInc == -1 && cInc == 0) {
            //same goes here
        }

        if (rInc == 1 && cInc == 1) {
            //same goes here
        }

        if (rInc == 1 && cInc == -1) {
            // same goes here
        }

        if (rInc == -1 && cInc == -1) {
            //same goes here
        }

        if (rInc == -1 && cInc == 1) {
            // same goes here
        }


        return isOverlapping;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Please present [actual code from your project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for review.

Comment: @greybeard added the actual code.

Comment: The method doesn't compile by itself, and the variable names are so cryptic that I can't make heads or tails about what the code is supposed to do.  Unless the code compiles, I can't refactor it.

Comment: While this claims to be object-oriented I don't see any classes in the question. One of the ways to reduce code duplication is to create a base class and inherit the the base class for the common functions. Code design / object design is off-topic for code review where we review code that is working as expected to provide suggestions on how to improve that code. Try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask or https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: `//same goes here` No no, you either post the code and we can help you with a review, or you don't post the code. It looks like you got something going here, but please be complete when posting your code or you're making it needlessly difficult on the reviewers. We don't handle that very well.

Comment: @Mast this was my first question, I'll remember all the tips the reviewers have added and will make sure that I don't repeat the same mistakes.

Comment: Good! For maximum effect, reading the [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) might help too. Best of luck with your next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the great things about working with OOP, is instance methods and polymorphism.

If you add methods in a `Line` class to perform this logic. Then you hold several instances of the line, and move each with a simple method call. You can also make use of inner properties to make the calculation simpler.

This may not help enough. You said there are 8 *types* of lines, so I'm assuming there some difference in the logic. In other words, you can make 8 classes which `extend Line` and customizes the general logic from `Line` to make the implementation work for the line type.

An example code for the concept:

````
class Line {
    private double motionSpeed;

    public void move(Direction direction) {
        switch(direction) {
            case UP:
                moveBy(0, -motionSpeed);
                break;
            // other cases
        }
    }

    // child classes will implement how to actually move
    protected abstract void moveBy(double x, double y);
}
class LineType1 extends Line {

    @Override
    protected void moveBy(double x, double y) {
        // actually move
    } 
}

class UI {
     private Collection<Line> lines;

     public void moveLines(Direction direction) {
         for (Line line : lines) {
             line.move(direction);
         } 
     }
}
```
````

Comment: To sum it up, I need to **create more Classes** and make use of **polymorphism and dynamic binding** to replace multiple switch and if-else constructs.

Comment: Thats the OOP option, yeah. If you already have a list class, then you can just use it.